# In custom adaptor, where is the file's title property I have to set?

Tags: google-search-appliance

I'm making custom file adaptor using [adaptor library](http://googlegsa.github.io/adaptor/index.html).

In my adaptor `getDocContent()`, I retrieve file from URL, and set the content to the Response's OutputStream like [sharepoint connector do](https://github.com/googlegsa/library/blob/9fcf3fdb08e06780a040bdff32cfd30453e2494d/src/com/google/enterprise/adaptor/IOHelper.java#L40).

So, I thought "Where is the file's title property I have to set? This is just a content."

As I was thinking, the file does not hit by it's title on the GSA search API.  Also by File Extension Filter.

Answer (score 0):

When developing a connector for Google Search Appliance using the Adaptor Framework, you have a few options on how to display metadata. You can send metadata via HTTP headers, but this lacks somehow. For example, when your metadata is too long, it will get truncated (because of it's size).
Since some time we use [Handlebars](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java) for templating in GSA connectors. You pass your retrieved object to Handlebars, after which you can compose an HTML document such as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="description" content="{{object.description}}"/>
    <meta name="filetype" content="{{object.filetype}}"/>
    <title>{{object.title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{object.title}}</title>
    <p>{{object.description}}</p>
    <p>{{object.someMoreContent}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

So when you getDocContent method is invoked (usually, when GSA crawls you connector), it will crawl the page you design with HTML and HandleBars. Very straightforward and easy to maintain!